# Use of possessive in "seven years' experience"

Tags: grammar, possessives

I am attempting to write a personal statement at the beginning of a resume and am having a quandry as to how to write the following:

> I am a super hero with **seven years' experience** in blowing out fires with my exhalation...

I assume that since the experience doesn't belong to the seven instances of years, this is incorrect use of the plural possessive.

How can I write this statement properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Common usage would be **years'** when talking about more than one year in a possessive sense. Seven years' means it belongs to a **group** of more than one year.

> I am a super hero with seven *years'* experience in blowing out fires with my exhalation.

Compare with:

> It had been *years* since I last blew out fires with my exhalation.

For reference: [Purdue OWL- Plural Possessive center](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/621/01/)

Answer (score 4):

To avoid using the apostrophe, you can write

> I am a super hero with seven years of experience in blowing out fires
>   with my exhalation.

However using the apostrophe and writing

> I am a super hero with seven years' experience in blowing out fires
>   with my exhalation

is fine, because it need not mean literal possession. Here the apostrophe simply means that the experience is related to the seven years in some way, much like in *men's shoes* or *doctor's appointment*.